# Is there a list of the version output produced by different installations?

Tags: java, versioning

I have a shell script that should detect an incompatible (too old) java installation.

Unfortunately, the output of `java -version` seems to be highly variable, so is there some website that has collected as many examples as possible so I can test my script against them?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar piece of functionality, i.e. detect an outdated version of Java. I found the same issue, i.e. java -version has too much variability, especially because my needs were at the major version granularity. I found that the System property java.vm.specification.version was actually what was needed (and maybe what you really need as well).
I solved it at runtime in my application, however, what was done here could easily be applied as a small stand-alone app.

```
final String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version");
final String[] versionInfo = StringUtils.split(javaVersion, ".");
if (Integer.parseInt(versionInfo[0]) == 1 && Integer.parseInt(versionInfo[1]) < 8) {
    logger.error("Java 1.8 required. Unable to run with Java " + javaVersion);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Java 1.8 required. Runtime java version: " + javaVersion);
}
```

Comment: Using the specification version property to get a cleaner version string is a good idea, by your code will fail with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for more recent Java versions that don't contain a dot in the specification version.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked past 1.8 yet, as it was only recently that I was able to add this enforcement (yes, within the last year, we were still 1.7 compliant).  We're supposed to start supporting Java 9 late in the year, and I will get a chance to revist this code.